# Push contents of one buffer to another buffer interactively in vim

Tags: vim

I would love to create a vim add-on that pushes parts of one buffer to another buffer *interactively* (or as interactive as possible). The latter buffer can be considered read-only, but it should be possible to push multiple other buffers to it. In order to make clear what I want to do, I am going to provide an example. For the sake of simplicity, let us assume that I have two files `A`, `B` and I want to automatically merge them in a file `AB`.

The file `A` is given by:

```
# unique_tag_A
Contents of file A
```

The file `B` is given by:

```
# unique_tag_B
Contents of file B
```

The file `AB` is given by:

```
# unique_tag_A
Contents of file A

# unique_tag_B
Contents of file B
```

If I change file `A` to

```
# unique_tag_A
Contents (file A)
```

I want to change the file `AB` as automatically as possible to:

```
# unique_tag_A
Contents (file A)

# unique_tag_B
Contents of file B
```

I read documentation about vim hooks, but honestly, I am new to this and it seems that I would have to take care of a lot of stuff. I guess I could get some not so interactive add-on working that copies from one buffer to the other, but ideally text would appear in the other buffer while typing and not, e.g. when leaving insert mode. If this makes it easier, I could drop the other file `B` (even though my example seems to be pointless). I am wondering whether this has been done before, if you have any references or tips? I am sorry for the vague question, but there seem to be many options and it seems impossible to explore all of them.

Comment: “ideally text would appear in the other buffer while typing and not, e.g. when leaving insert mode” — I’m not certain that I’m understanding the question overall correctly, but something to do with [`TextChangedI`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#TextChangedI) might help.

Comment: Vague indeed. What's the real-life use case behind this?!

Comment: @IngoKarkat Using advanced features (like syntax checking) on source code in a literate programming setting without touching other tools (too much). This is just one option I am thinking about. And maybe its the worst idea ever, but I was interested whether it would be possible.

Comment: For that, I would rather pre-process / filter the original files (remove comments etc.), and have the tools work on the temp copies.